# Segundo forloop.counter no imprime nada en pantalla

Tags: python, django, html

Estoy construyendo un carrusel de imágenes usando Foundation Orbit, para la parte de los **bullets** tengo un error al usar dos etiquetas `forloop.counter`, las necesito para imprimir en pantalla el número del elemento del carrusel, uno en forma "Humanizada" y el otro en entero, pero ocurre que no imprime nada en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está el código que estoy usando en mi template.

```
<nav class="orbit-bullets">
    {% for affiliation in affiliations %}
        <button {% if forloop.first %}class="is-active"{% endif %} data-slide="{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            <span class="show-for-sr">
                {% blocktrans %}{{ forloop.counter0|ordinal }} slide details.{% endblocktrans %}
            </span>
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <span class="show-for-sr">{% trans 'Current Slide' %}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </button>
    {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

Como pueden ver la idea es que imprima `3rd slide details.` y en vez de esto me imprime únicamente la cadena fija.

Cuando quito la etiqueta adicional `ordinal` resulta que no tengo número, por lo que deduzco que el problema no es humanizar, el problema es imprimir el número:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás usando `{% load humanize %}`?

Comment: Quité la etiqueta `javascript` ya que no le encuentro la relación

Comment: El problema no es lo de humanize, es que no me está imprimiendo el número.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según la documentación de [blocktrans](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag), para acceder a atributos de objetos o emplear filtros tienes que asociar la expresión a una variable local al bloque:

```
{% blocktrans with counter=forloop.counter0|ordinal %}{{ counter }} slide details.{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Efectivamente, muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @SalahAdDin no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta :)